# Should I install new software in Debian?

Tags: debian, java, debian-squeeze

I know Debian is very stable because it used old kernel, packages and so on. Of course, it make Debian more security. So should I install new software/package in Debian, for examples Java 7? Thanks!

Comment: You have things exactly backwards. Old =/= stable, in fact, it generally means it is less stable. It also makes it less secure (that is because organizations make changes to make things more secure and stable). The question as to what to install is more based on need, and is it coming from a trusted source than is it old. Software is not wine. It does not get better with age.

Comment: @soandos, you're wrong for the same reason OP is: stability has nothing to do with being old vs being new, it's about having well-defined behavior. Security problems get fixed in stable packaged versions ensuring those security patches do not break things (such as APIs, ABIs and even known non-security-related bugs).

Answer (score 3):

No, Maybe and Yes.

In general I wouldn't recommend going off the versions in the repository in case there's something that relies on it (python is notorious for this, and I can't remember anything tied to a specific version of Java). If it's in backports or some other official repository, I'd think it would be tested, so it may be a good option.

If you *really* need something that *must* have the latest Java, then it may be an idea to try *after* a backup.

If you need newer packages, but want to stick to Debian, why not go for [Testing](http://wiki.debian.org/DebianTesting) or [Sid](http://wiki.debian.org/DebianUnstable)?

Answer (score 2):

As I already stated in my comment to your post, stability Debian strives to provide is about well-defined behaviour.  Hence to answer your question you should ask yourself:

- What disruption such an upgrade would cause to the rest of the system? This means what happens to other packages which need JVM to work and which are already installed or will be installed on that system?
- How are you intending to deal with security upgrades?
- Are you willing to possibly sustain extra pain in the neck when upgrading your system to the next stable release?

Another thing to note is that certain packages are not too self-contained: for instance, the newer packages for JVM can depend on fresher versions of libraries which are not available in the current stable release.

In the end, here's my personal opinion, if you're certain you *need* the freshest JVM and are certain other software won't break, either try to backport the latest packaged JVM to the stable release or consider upgrading to testing.  I don't like the latter idea *right now* as it's not frozen yet (the freeze is only planned to the second half of June).

Answer (score 0):

Okay. I'm not a Debian user, but an Arch Linux user, which is rolling release, that is, you always have new software. Installing Java 7 or not just depends on you. Do you really need extreme stability? Are you using it for a server? Assuming you are not, then I would perfectly install it. Debian as a community is awesome and if there were any problem, it would be fixed really fast. Furthermore, Java 7, which is pretty famous, has been probably tested a lot.

I would install it, if I were you. It's going to work with no problem. Install new software unless you really need extreme stability. Don't worry.

My two cents.